# Using same ssh key for Parallels

Tags: mac, ssh, git

I have a Mac and am running Parallels that has Windows 7 on it.  I have an ssh key that I use to connect to github.  When I go to my Parallels/Windows 7 and try to do

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get permission denied (publickey).

If I create a new key on my Windows 7 VM, will that overwrite my current key that my Mac terminal uses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is stored in the folder `~/.ssh/` on your Mac. For example, on my system I have files called `github_rsa` (private key) and `github_rsa.pub` (public key). You can copy/paste the private key over to your Windows machine and [install it there](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows) – it's just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @miken32's answer should work.  You should also be able to do it the way you suggest, creating a new key pair on the VM.  Unless you have configured the VM to share the `~/.ssh/` directory on the host, nothing you do on the VM should have any effect on your existing key pair.

Note to self:  never say "nothing"!